# Document search using solr and drupal

Tags: drupal, solr, module

I want to add a module to my Drupal CMS (preferably latest version 7), so that I can add some pdf documents, it automatically indexes and gives me a tool for searching in those files (Assuming that I can independently run solr).

I want to be able to use the capabilities of Solr such as facets. Is there a Drupal module ready to use or I should come up with a wrapping idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the following modules: search_api, search_api_solr, facetapi